# Add contents of a file to an existing Kubernetes secret

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets

I have an existing generic Kubernetes secret that exported as YAML (using `kubectl get secret -o yaml > secret.yaml`), looks like this:

```yaml
kind: Secret
apiVersion: v1
type: Opaque
metadata:
  name: some-secret-key-files
data:
  host1.example.com.key: c2VjcmV0IG51bWJlciBvbmUK
  host2.example.com.key: c2VjcmV0IG51bWJlciB0d28K
```

Now I have a new key file named `host3.example.com.key`, with these contents:

```
secret number three
```

What is easiest way to add the contents of this file base64-encoded to `secret.yaml`, so that in the end it looks like this:

```yaml
kind: Secret
apiVersion: v1
type: Opaque
metadata:
  name: some-secret-key-files
data:
  host1.example.com.key: c2VjcmV0IG51bWJlciBvbmUK
  host2.example.com.key: c2VjcmV0IG51bWJlciB0d28K
  host3.example.com.key: c2VjcmV0IG51bWJlciB0aHJlZQo=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, exporting the secret to a YAML file was not needed at all. With `kubectl patch secret` this can be done 'online' like this:

```bash
kubectl patch secret some-secret-key-files --patch="{\"data\": {\"host3.example.com.key\": \"$(base64 -w0 host3.example.com.key)\"}}"
```

This will add a new file entry to the existing secret `some-secret-key-files`, and use `base64(1)` to base64 encode the contents of the local `host3.example.com.key` file.